# Create SQL Query in function or PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am trying to create function inside MySQL to create several queries for example :

```
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE PROCEDURE queryBuilder(_tableName varchar(100))
    BEGIN
          SET @str_query = 'SET @countRows = 0;SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @countRows FROM';
          SET @str_query = CONCAT(@str_query,_tableName, '; SELECT @countRows');

         PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str_query;

         EXECUTE stmt1;

   END|
   DELIMITER;
```

but it doesn't work? how can i change to work? I know i can create IF statement but i want something with more flexibility.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i can create varchar then try to executed, but when i trying add set @count in to string query MySQL give an errors .

Comment: it would be helpful if you post the exact code and error @milad

Comment: @TomV i changed my function to PROCEDURE but return empty row?

Answer (score 0):

- Don't set @countRows twice.
- Don't combine two queries into a single "statement".
- Watch out for syntax errors when concatenating without a space.
- `SELECT @str_query;` for debugging.